# remote class file in java

Tags: java, class

i have an class file (`UT.class` / `package ROOT`) that i want to acsess from evry projekt in the folder.
(paths are like so: every projekt is in `C:\users\%username%\Javacoding\` the file `UT.class` is in `C:\..\Javacoding\ROOT` and i want to access it from like `C:\..\Javacoding\FirstProj\src\file.java` or `C:\..\Javacoding\SecondProj\src\file.java`
 how do i do that ??
(or how do i have to set my CLASSPATH, the current state is only `.;C:\users\%username%\Javacoding\ROOT`)

Comment: What kind of IDE are you using? If eclipse, you can Root project as dependency to other projects, say FirstProj and SecondProj.

Comment: can you please post the first line of UT.java (that one that begins with "package"). You have to point your classpath to the top of the folder package folder hierachy and i guess this is C:\users\%username%\Javacoding If UT.class is a kind of library you should consider to put it in a .jar file and point the classpath to this jar file like C:\users\%username%\Javacoding\ut.jar . And keep in mind that package names are lowercase by convention.

Comment: the first line of my code is: `package ROOT;`

Comment: all solved (i had to set the `CLASSPATH` variable to `.;C:\Users\Peer_2\Dropbox\JAVACODING\` now its fixt!!